# Accepts nested attributes safe params with jsonb and variable keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, jsonb, accepts-nested-attributes

I am attempting to allow parameters to go through my controller for a `data` attribute that is of type `jsonb`, the hash looks like so:

```
data: 
  { "en" =>
    {
      "activities_text" => "Activities",
      "playlists_text" => "Playlists",
      "additional_playlists_text" => "Additional Playlists"
    },
    "es" =>
    {
      "activities_text" => "Actividades",
      "playlists_text" => "Lista de Actividades",
      "additional_playlists_text" => "Listas de Actividades Adicionales"
    }
  }
```

I got my form to work and I can save data successfully, but only for one of the language keys. The issue is happening because in my safe params array I have the following:

`text_customization_attributes: [:id, data: [es: [:activities_text, :playlists_text, :additional_playlists_text]]]`

I need to be able to allow through both `en:` as well as `es:` and potentially any other language `keys` I may add in the future. I naively thought maybe adding
both the line above as well as this: `text_customization_attributes: [:id, data: [en: [:activities_text, :playlists_text, :additional_playlists_text]]]`
would work but one overrides the other and only the last permitted param wins.

How could I let through both `es:` and `en:`?

---

I was able to save the whole hash by using this

```
text_customization_attributes: [:id, data: [en: [:activities_text, :playlists_text, :additional_playlists_text],
es: [:activities_text, :playlists_text, :additional_playlists_text]]]
```

but it seems very hackish. There must be a better way.

Comment: I improved the solution above by iterating over the available locales with a method

 `def dynamic_text_cust_attrs
  cust_attrs = {}
  I18n.available_locales.each {|e| cust_attrs[e] = [:activities_text, :playlists_text, :additional_playlists_text] }
  cust_attrs
end`

and then using the hash generated like so in my safe params array:

`text_customization_attributes: [:id, data: [ dynamic_text_cust_attrs ]]`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there may be some keys other than `en` or `es`, somehow, we must tell which parameters are permitted. In your case, you can map to an empty hash like,

```
text_customization_attributes: [:id, data: {}]
```

But, it is a bit vulnerable as it opens the door to an arbitrary input.

[Reference -> edgeguides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters):

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to not do that since as you said it makes the app less secure.